# ODE45 in MATLAB with second order differential equations

Tags: matlab, ode

I was wondering how one would use ODE45 in MATLAB to solve higher (second) order differential equation initial value problems.

For example
    x''+5x'+2x=0

where 
    x(0)=1
    x'(0)=3

Comment: These two videos should give you a good idea of how set-up and solve these problems with Matlab: [Blanchard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fx3bl4oA_0U) and [Lewin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFF_Isz_TjU).

Answer (score 1):

You make it into a system of first order. For instance, by defining `y=x'`, so that `x'=y` and `y'=x''=-5y-2x`.

```
dotx = function dxdt(t,x)
    dotx = [ x(2)  -5*x(2)-2*x(1) ]
end

ode45(@dxdt, [0 T], [ 1 3 ])
```